# Illustrator CC export svg changes sparkle shape to circle

Tags: adobe-illustrator, svg, export

i've got 3 "sparkle" shapes. When I export the svg the exported one converts the sparkles to cirlces. I've messed with the setting and cannot figure it out. thanks.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Just a guess here without seeing your Illustrator file- how are the Sparkles constructed ? if they are a circle shape with an effect applied you should object> expand appearance prior  to exporting the svg.

Comment: Yes, used pucker & bloat distort & transform effect. I did expand appearance prior to export but still converted to circles. I just tried another approach: I recreated the sparkles with snap to pixel, started with a square, used overlapping circles to "cut out" the sides then rotated and rounded the points slightly. that seems to export fine.

Comment: Hmmm- interesting- glad you found a way to make it work...

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue many times and I finally found a solution that works for me. So what I did was "copy and paste in place" the same shape and make sure **BOTH** are selected and go to **pathfinder** and click on **Unite** and then in the corner setting of pathfinder choose **Make Compound shape** This should now work!

Comment: `Object > Expand Appearance` No need to for all that copy/pathfinder stuff.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by adding an anchor point randomly on the curves of the sparkle. It didn't affect the smoothness of the lines and it exported with no problem.

[image]